# The property on type cannot be set because collection is already set to an EntityCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity

I am trying to update an Entity which has navigation property attached to it.

```
public partial class Stock
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public virtual int StockId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string StockName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations
    ...
}
```

This works well when I just insert the entity in the Database, but when I update I get the error as:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Trade.Sales.Presentation.Admin but
>   was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The property 'Locations' on type
>   'Stock_4654D170FFCE308BB1B9AF1E2018476DF2E1C2E1DBA137F58AB96BCB9FAFC859'
>   cannot be set because the collection is already set to an
>   EntityCollection.

I went through some of the other posts, but the solution which is given is:

Modifying the properties as non-virtual i.e. Removing 'virtual' keyword. However my senior says this cannot be accepted as this class is generated automatically and will change once the Entity is updated from the DB.

**Do we have any other solution for this to be worked ?**

Comment: Showing the code that is actually throwing the exception would probably help a lot. According to the exception there must be somewhere a line like `stock.Locations = someLocationsCollection` that is the problem, I think. Perhaps using instead `stock.Locations.Clear(); foreach (var loc in someLocationsCollection) stock.Locations.Add(loc);` is a replacement for setting the collection as a whole that already solves the problem.

Comment: Hi Slaumna this works well. The foreach made that work.. Could you reply as an answer to be marked? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely there is a line like `stock.Locations = myLocationCollection` that is causing the problem. What you would like to do is the following:

```
stock.Locations.Clear(); 
foreach (var loc in myLocationsCollection) 
    stock.Locations.Add(loc);
```

It is a workaround that can be used to set the collection as a whole.